# Edit It Raw HD(1080p) Video

Tags: video

So hard drive capacity is not a concern for me.

I just would like my videos to render instantly.

Is there a way to edit in raw in FCP7 or some other video editing software?

Comment: I have literally no idea what you are asking. Please refine your question and clarify what you're trying to do and what's not working.

Comment: @MoritzLost so I believe its called Mercury Playback after doing some research in Premiere.  Does that help or do I need another example?

Comment: Is your concern with the responsive and speed of the system during editing? Or during export of your edited project?

Comment: @Mulvya I didn't think it altered exporting of the project so just the responsive during editing.

Answer (score 1):

RAW files are also known as *digital negatives* and therefore cannot be used directly for editing video or other purposes. They must first be processed.

To process them you will additional software. And this will depend on your needs. From which device did you get this RAW data? To which format would you like to convert it?

For example, if you use the 5K video camera *RED Scarlet Dragon*, then you RAW files would be in **REDCODE raw format**.

To convert this to readable format you may use *REDCINE-X raw viewer* which, by the way, spits out in playable **ProRes** files.

Finally, you can take this into *Adobe Premier Pro* to do your editing.

To conclude it would all depend on your needs and why you would like to work on RAW files in the first place.

Check these links for more info:

- [List of RAW Formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_codecs#Lossless_video_compression).
- [Video Workflow: Using RAW Files.](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/explora/video/tips-and-solutions/video-workflow-using-raw-files)
- [RAW files processing by extracting DNG frames.](http://www.magiclantern.fm/forum/?topic=5654.0)
- [Importing RAW files in FCP.](http://www.rippletraining.com/articles/2015/01/28/importing-r3d-raw-into-final-cut-pro-x/)

Comment: Dv files are a raw format but not what you are taking about I believe

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use the antiquated FCP7 which is not able to handle RAW files due to the limitations of the software. Moving to FCPX will allow you to edit the native files (if supported) or will do the trans-coding for you in the background.

If you do not want to buy FCPX you can try Davinci Resolve 12.5 which is free and is a powerful editing system and can handle a large variety of file formats.

I would advise converting to a more editable format (system dependent PC/MAC) and or creating proxies. The performance of the software is going to depends alot on how good your editing system is, CPU, Ram, GPU, HDD, SSD, Raid etc.

Editing in "RAW" is not really even done by the "Professionals" in Hollywood as the files are massive and working between teams in different parts of the film would take for ever to copy and move. they would make smaller HQ proxies at a fraction of the size and work using them and in the final stages relink the HQ master files and export a final etc.

Comment: I'm not concerned with file size just rendering speed

Comment: Import, create proxies, do all your editing, relink to master files for final export.
Other option is buying a SUPER fast raid with SSD's and or with a  fiberchannel to edit RAW.